# Error: 'Stray start tag div'

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I was running the W3C validator on the internal page of website and I received this error regarding Stray start tag div:

Error: **Stray start tag div.**

```
<div id="fb-root">
```

Please help me with the corect code.

**My Code:**

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12';
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Comment: not sure why you tagged this with php? anyway, please show the whole html code.

Comment: The above code is Javascript SDK code for Facebook like button. Please check the above code in this URL: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

Comment: the error suggests that you may have placed it at a wrong position, that is why it´s important to show your html code. you can also just do some research, google will give you many results for that error.

Comment: Thank you. I am able to resolve the error by placing the script before closing of <body> tag.

Answer (score 3):

The error suggests that you may have placed the code at a wrong position. Make sure it is in the body-tag.